# Missing log file

Tags: java, cron, raspberrypi

I wrote a .jar file that is supposed to be run once a day that interacts with Google App Engine.  When I run it from the computer, it runs just fine and creates a logfile that details some statistics.  I transferred it over to a Raspberry Pi and it runs via crontab.

The first time I ran it, I got a permission denied in syslog.  I read that using 'sudo crontab -e' would fix that.  Now I no longer get the error but my logfile doesn't appear.

Here is the portion of the code that is to create the logfile:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("log" + format.format(date) + ".txt");
writer.println("Total Themes: " + numThemes + "\r\n");
writer.println("Active Themes: " + numActiveThemes + "\r\n");
writer.println("Inactive Themes: " + numInactiveThemes + "\r\n");
writer.println("Total Sales: " + numSales + "\r\n");
writer.println("Total Price Changes: " + numPriceChanges + "\r\n");
writer.println("Total Time: " + seconds + " seconds" + "\r\n");
writer.close();
```

Crontab:

```
0 2 * * * java -jar /mnt/data/scripts/updater_pricing.jar
```

What am I missing about the switch from Windows that is preventing the creation of the logfile?

Edit: I can run the `.jar` file manually (using `sudo java -r /mnt/data/scripts/updater_pricing.jar`) and the logfile is created.  Not working w/cron though.

Edit2: `/etc/log/syslog` has:

```
Feb  8 21:46:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[10841]: (root) CMD (java -jar /mnt/data/scripts/updater_pricing.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  The email was being sent because I had some lines of `System.out.println()`

The logfiles were being created, just in the wrong place.  I had to modify the original file line to be:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("/mnt/data/scripts/" + "log" + format.format(date) + ".txt");
```